# Как в sqlite3 python сделать топ рейтинга

Tags: python, sqlite3

Допустим есть БД:

```
query = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(30),
        age INTEGER(3),
        sex INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        balance INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 2000,
        login VARCHAR(15),
        password VARCHAR(20)
    );
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS casino(
        name VARCHAR(50),
        description TEXT(300),
        balance BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 10000
    )
    """
```

и мне надо по балансу сделать рейтинг игроков.

Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Написать запрос, который будет выводить из таблицы пользователей, отсортированных по балансу в порядке убывания и ограничив выборку N записями

Answer (score 0):

Запрос из таблицы `users`, сортирующий записи по полю `balance` от большего к меньшему (из-за оператора `DESC`), и возвращающий максимум 5 записей:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 5
```

Синтаксис SELECT подробно описан в документации: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html